# clang Implicit conversion warning in template function. Is making the conversion explicit the right solution?

Tags: c++, json, double, implicit-conversion, integer-overflow

From updating clang to 10 this code now gives `implicit conversion warnings.` This is for parsing JSON and since JSON works with JavaScript, and JavaScript has loose conversion rules I'm not sure how to deal with the overflow properly. Is this a situation where I want to disable the warning, or should I make the conversion of type explicit in the template? How would I do that with a template function? Ideally, I'd like to use a c style cast. Any other possible solutions?

```
    template <typename T>
    bool TryConvertNumber(const FJsonValue& InValue, T& OutNumber)
    {
        double Double;

        if (InValue.TryGetNumber(Double) && (Double >= TNumericLimits<T>::Min()) && (Double <= TNumericLimits<T>::Max()))
        {
            OutNumber = static_cast<T>(FMath::RoundHalfFromZero(Double));

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    bool FJsonValue::TryGetNumber(float& OutNumber) const
    {
        double Double;

        if (TryGetNumber(Double))
        {
            OutNumber = static_cast<float>(Double);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    bool FJsonValue::TryGetNumber(uint64& OutNumber) const
    {
        return TryConvertNumber(*this, OutNumber);
    }

    bool FJsonValue::TryGetNumber(int64& OutNumber) const
    {
        return TryConvertNumber(*this, OutNumber);
    }
```

Comment: `Is making the conversion explicit the right solution?` If your intention was to make a conversion (and that intention holds for all possible template arguments) then yes, making the conversion explicit would be the right solution.

Comment: I'm just not sure how to format that for a template function, considering there are a lot of other number types being handled as well. I'm trying to keep the conversion c style if possible.

Comment: Not sure if all would follow, but I consider C-style conversions in C++ code as bad coding style...

Comment: @Aconcagua I work in game dev. They tend to stick to C features.